# How to synchronize two cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that is supposed to keep some cells synchronized with their respective cell at another sheet.

If I change `B2000TBES`, which is cell I29 on sheet "Kalkylsammanställning", it is supposed to change `B2000TBES`, which is cell H195 on sheet "B2000".

The whole code. (A few lines essentially do nothing, because this is pasted behind a worksheet.)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim htCell1 As Range
Dim htCell2 As Range
Dim htCell3 As Range
Dim htCell4 As Range
Dim htCell5 As Range
Dim htCell6 As Range

Dim hCell1 As Range
Dim hCell2 As Range
Dim hCell3 As Range
Dim hCell4 As Range
Dim hCell5 As Range
Dim hCell6 As Range
Dim hCell7 As Range
Dim hCell8 As Range
Dim hCell9 As Range
Dim hCell10 As Range

Dim rCell1 As Range
Dim rCell2 As Range
Dim rCell3 As Range
Dim rCell4 As Range
Dim rCell5 As Range
Dim rCell6 As Range
Dim rCell7 As Range
Dim rCell8 As Range
Dim rCell9 As Range
Dim rCell10 As Range

Dim peCell1 As Range
Dim peCell2 As Range
Dim peCell3 As Range
Dim peCell4 As Range
Dim peCell5 As Range
Dim peCell6 As Range
Dim peCell7 As Range
Dim peCell8 As Range
Dim peCell9 As Range
Dim peCell10 As Range

Dim paCell1 As Range
Dim paCell2 As Range
Dim paCell3 As Range
Dim paCell4 As Range
Dim paCell5 As Range
Dim paCell6 As Range
Dim paCell7 As Range
Dim paCell8 As Range
Dim paCell9 As Range
Dim paCell10 As Range

Dim speCell1 As Range
Dim speCell2 As Range
Dim speCell3 As Range
Dim speCell4 As Range
Dim speCell5 As Range
Dim speCell6 As Range
Dim speCell7 As Range
Dim speCell8 As Range
Dim speCell9 As Range
Dim speCell10 As Range

Dim spaCell1 As Range
Dim spaCell2 As Range
Dim spaCell3 As Range
Dim spaCell4 As Range
Dim spaCell5 As Range
Dim spaCell6 As Range
Dim spaCell7 As Range
Dim spaCell8 As Range
Dim spaCell9 As Range
Dim spaCell10 As Range

Dim varRanta As Range

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Set htCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("HTIDS")
Set htCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S3000").Range("S3000HTID")
Set htCell3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2000").Range("S2000HTID")
Set htCell4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K2000").Range("K2000HTID")
Set htCell5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000HTID")
Set htCell6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K10").Range("K10HTID")

Set hCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S3000HYRAS")
Set hCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S3000").Range("S3000HYRA")
Set hCell3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S2000HYRAS")
Set hCell4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2000").Range("S2000HYRA")
Set hCell5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K2000HYRAS")
Set hCell6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K2000").Range("K2000HYRA")
Set hCell7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("B2000HYRAS")
Set hCell8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000HYRA")
Set hCell9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K10HYRAS")
Set hCell10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K10").Range("K10HYRA")

Set rCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S3000FAKTORS")
Set rCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S3000").Range("S3000FAKTOR")
Set rCell3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S2000FAKTORS")
Set rCell4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2000").Range("S2000FAKTOR")
Set rCell5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K2000FAKTORS")
Set rCell6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K2000").Range("K2000FAKTOR")
Set rCell7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("B2000FAKTORS")
Set rCell8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000FAKTOR")
Set rCell9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K10FAKTORS")
Set rCell10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K10").Range("K10FAKTOR")

Set peCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S3000TBES")
Set peCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S3000").Range("S3000TBE")
Set peCell3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S2000TBES")
Set peCell4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2000").Range("S2000TBE")
Set peCell5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K2000TBES")
Set peCell6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K2000").Range("K2000TBE")
Set peCell7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("B2000TBES")
Set peCell8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000TBE")
Set peCell9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K10TBES")
Set peCell10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K10").Range("K10TBE")

Set paCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S3000TBAS")
Set paCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S3000").Range("S3000TBA")
Set paCell3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S2000TBAS")
Set paCell4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2000").Range("S2000TBA")
Set paCell5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K2000TBAS")
Set paCell6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K2000").Range("K2000TBA")
Set paCell7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("B2000TBAS")
Set paCell8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000TBA")
Set paCell9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K10TBAS")
Set paCell10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K10").Range("K10TBA")

Set speCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S3000SPES")
Set speCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S3000").Range("S3000SPE")
Set speCell3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S2000SPES")
Set speCell4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2000").Range("S2000SPE")
Set speCell5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K2000SPES")
Set speCell6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K2000").Range("K2000SPE")
Set speCell7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("B2000SPES")
Set speCell8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000SPE")
Set speCell9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K10SPES")
Set speCell10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K10").Range("K10SPE")

Set spaCell1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S3000SPAS")
Set spaCell2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S3000").Range("S3000SPA")
Set spaCell3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("S2000SPAS")
Set spaCell4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("S2000").Range("S2000SPA")
Set spaCell5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K2000SPAS")
Set spaCell6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K2000").Range("K2000SPA")
Set spaCell7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("B2000SPAS")
Set spaCell8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000SPA")
Set spaCell9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("K10SPAS")
Set spaCell10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K10").Range("K10SPA")

Set varRanta = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("RANTAVAR")


Application.EnableEvents = False

Select Case Target.Address

Case varRanta.Address
Call Sum_Hyra

Case htCell1.Address
htCell2.Value = htCell1.Value
htCell3.Value = htCell1.Value
htCell4.Value = htCell1.Value
htCell5.Value = htCell1.Value
htCell6.Value = htCell1.Value

Case hCell1.Address
hCell2.Value = hCell1.Value
Case hCell2.Address
hCell1.Value = hCell2.Value
Case hCell3.Address
hCell4.Value = hCell3.Value
Case hCell4.Address
hCell3.Value = hCell4.Value
Case hCell5.Address
hCell6.Value = hCell5.Value
Case hCell6.Address
hCell5.Value = hCell6.Value
Case hCell7.Address
hCell8.Value = hCell7.Value
Case hCell8.Address
hCell7.Value = hCell8.Value
Case hCell9.Address
hCell10.Value = hCell9.Value
Case hCell10.Address
hCell9.Value = hCell10.Value

Case rCell1.Address
rCell2.Value = rCell1.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell2.Address
rCell1.Value = rCell2.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell3.Address
rCell4.Value = rCell3.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell4.Address
rCell3.Value = rCell4.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell5.Address
rCell6.Value = rCell5.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell6.Address
rCell5.Value = rCell6.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell7.Address
rCell8.Value = rCell7.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell8.Address
rCell7.Value = rCell8.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell9.Address
rCell10.Value = rCell9.Value
Call Sum_Hyra
Case rCell10.Address
rCell9.Value = rCell10.Value
Call Sum_Hyra

Case peCell1.Address
peCell2.Value = peCell1.Value
Case peCell2.Address
peCell1.Value = peCell2.Value
Case peCell3.Address
peCell4.Value = peCell3.Value
Case peCell4.Address
peCell3.Value = peCell4.Value
Case peCell5.Address
peCell6.Value = peCell5.Value
Case peCell6.Address
peCell5.Value = peCell6.Value
Case peCell7.Address
peCell8.Value = peCell7.Value
Case peCell8.Address
peCell7.Value = peCell8.Value
Case peCell9.Address
peCell10.Value = peCell9.Value
Case peCell10.Address
peCell9.Value = peCell10.Value

Case paCell1.Address
paCell2.Value = paCell1.Value
Case paCell2.Address
paCell1.Value = paCell2.Value
Case paCell3.Address
paCell4.Value = paCell3.Value
Case paCell4.Address
paCell3.Value = paCell4.Value
Case paCell5.Address
paCell6.Value = paCell5.Value
Case paCell6.Address
paCell5.Value = paCell6.Value
Case paCell7.Address
paCell8.Value = paCell7.Value
Case paCell8.Address
paCell7.Value = paCell8.Value
Case paCell9.Address
paCell10.Value = paCell9.Value
Case paCell10.Address
paCell9.Value = paCell10.Value

Case speCell1.Address
speCell2.Value = speCell1.Value
Case speCell2.Address
speCell1.Value = speCell2.Value
Case speCell3.Address
speCell4.Value = speCell3.Value
Case speCell4.Address
speCell3.Value = speCell4.Value
Case speCell5.Address
speCell6.Value = speCell5.Value
Case speCell6.Address
speCell5.Value = speCell6.Value
Case speCell7.Address
speCell8.Value = speCell7.Value
Case speCell8.Address
speCell7.Value = speCell8.Value
Case speCell9.Address
speCell10.Value = speCell9.Value
Case speCell10.Address
speCell9.Value = speCell10.Value

Case spaCell1.Address
spaCell2.Value = spaCell1.Value
Case spaCell2.Address
spaCell1.Value = spaCell2.Value
Case spaCell3.Address
spaCell4.Value = spaCell3.Value
Case spaCell4.Address
spaCell3.Value = spaCell4.Value
Case spaCell5.Address
spaCell6.Value = spaCell5.Value
Case spaCell6.Address
spaCell5.Value = spaCell6.Value
Case spaCell7.Address
spaCell8.Value = spaCell7.Value
Case spaCell8.Address
spaCell7.Value = spaCell8.Value
Case spaCell9.Address
spaCell10.Value = spaCell9.Value
Case spaCell10.Address
spaCell9.Value = spaCell10.Value

End Select

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Everything is working, EXCEPT it doesn't change `peCell8.Value` to `peCell7.Value` when `B2000TBES` is changed.

I have used "Step Into" and the code identifies the cells and their values.

I've meticulously scoured every letter and symbol in the code.

When I delete everything but the code for this specific operation, it works:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim peCell7 As Range
Dim peCell8 As Range

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Set peCell7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkylsammanställning").Range("B2000TBES")
Set peCell8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B2000").Range("B2000TBE")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Select Case Target.Address

Case peCell7.Address
peCell8.Value = peCell7.Value

End Select

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

To clarify:
Long code does what it should, except changing `peCell8.Value`.
Short code works.

Comment: It does not work because your code is a messy spaghetti code and exremly hard to maintain (sorry). Furthermore this code only syncronizes if only one cell is changed. If you for example copy/paste a range it does not sync and you end up with different values where you thought they were the same. I highly recommend to separate data and code. Data would be a list of worksheet/range addresses that should kept in sync. Put this list into a hidden sheet and make your code slim using the information in that hidden sheet. So you can easily add new sync ranges without modifying the code.

Comment: Further whenever you have the feeling you need to number your variable names you are doing something wrong. This is a very bad practice. Always use arrays instead of numbered variable names so you can at least loop through them instead of repeating code over and over.

Comment: Actually can't you use formulas instead of that code? For example you could use `=Sheet2!B3` to make any cell the same value as B3 in Sheet2

Comment: Thanks for your comment Pᴇʜ. This code started out as that small one in the beginning, but more of the same kind of functionality was requested a few times after that, and thus this messy spaghetti. The issue of copying and pasting a range won't be an issue, it's just not how the worksheet is being used. 
How would I even go about using arrays instead?
The code being messy has nothing to do with why it doesn't work though, since EVERY other operation works. Just not that particular one.

Comment: I want to be able to make changes in both cells and make sure the corresponding cell synchronizes.

Comment: So in which worksheet is this code running? Because it can only handle changes in the sheet it is written in. And are your named ranges defined in a sheet scope or in a workbook scope? • Without clarifing this cannot be answered. You might think this code works but if it really does it only does by accident (and not reliable).

Comment: As I wrote in the OP, I'm aware some lines do nothing. But they are running on all sheets. This code is on the "Master"-sheet, where everything is supposed to be summed up. The other sheets are running only the code relevant to them. The named ranges are defined on every sheet.

Comment: Well, please open the name manager (Ribbon › Formula › Name Manager) and either post a screenshot or tell what does the column "Range" there say? Is it `Workbook` or a worksheet name for your named ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a (hidden) worksheet called `SyncTable` like below:

[image]
*<sub>Image 1: SyncTable shows on which change which sync should be performed.</sub>*

Make sure the names `SyncA`, `SyncB`, etc exist in any worsheet of your workbook scope (Ribbon › Formula › Name Manager › Column "Range" needs to be `Workbook` for these names).

[image]
*<sub>Image 2: "Arbeitsmappe" = Workbook. All names need to be in the workbook scope.</sub>*

The following code needs to be placed (only once) into the `ThisWorkbook` scope:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo SAVE_EXIT
    
    Dim CellName As String
    CellName = vbNullString 'initialize
    
    'check if cell has a name
    On Error Resume Next
    CellName = Target.Name.Name
    On Error GoTo SAVE_EXIT
    
    If CellName <> vbNullString Then
        'check if cell should be synced to …
        Dim SyncTo As Variant
        SyncTo = Application.VLookup(CellName, Worksheets("SyncTable").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        
        If Not IsError(SyncTo) Then
            Dim Destination As Range
            Set Destination = Nothing 'initialize
            
            'check if sync to destination names exist
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Destination = Range(SyncTo)
            On Error GoTo SAVE_EXIT
            
            If Not Destination Is Nothing Then
                'names exist so sync
                Range(SyncTo).Value = Target.Value
            Else
                MsgBox "Named range '" & SyncTo & "' could not be found, check names", vbCritical
            End If
        End If
    End If

    
SAVE_EXIT: 'make sure you never end up with disabled events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

Then finally have your named ranges like shown below (note they are all in one worksheet but this is only for illustration purpose they can be in different ones).

[image]
*<sub>Image 3: Here the syncs are performed exactly as defined in the SyncTable.</sub>*

This way you have a clean short code and a SyncTable that can easily be extendet. You just need to add your names like `B2000TBES` and `B2000TBE`. If you want to sync in both directions you have to add them the other way round too `B2000TBE` and `B2000TBES`. If you want to sync one cell into multiple ones list them comma separated like the first entry.

Note that you cannot use normal cell addresses this only works with named ranges.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. I'm sure this works fine, and if I ever start a new project I will follow this procedure instead. But since 99% of my code works, and literally 25 other cells are paired with their respective cell on each underlying worksheet without any issues, I was hoping there would be a quick fix to this. But I don't expect anyone to comb through my "messy spaghetti" as you put it ;) I'll mark this answer as solved. Thanks again for your input!